# ODBC iterate table without storing in memory

Tags: database, database-design, odbc, iterator

I need to have a way to iterate through a database table without actually storing it in memory anywhere. I want to essentially read through the rows like an input iterator.

I've tried using cursors with a select statement (select * from table_name), but this retrieves the entire table and feeds it back to be one row at a time. So this solution is no good. Instead, I need it to only feed me each row as I ask for it.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll just want to use a forward only cursor.  Your DB will need to support this.  For detials, see [MSDN's How to: Use Cursors.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403326.aspx)

If you're using SQL Server, you can use a [Fast Forward-Only Cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131029.aspx), which provides extra benefits.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However I have already looked into Cursors and they are not what I'm looking for. They save the data before iterating through it. Thus it takes a long time with a large database to execute a 'select' query. I want to just be able fetch the data row by row without having it load into memory first. I want to read it straight from the database to ensure it is fast. Right now it is very slow and sometimes crashes if the database is too large

Comment: Forward only cursors don't "save the data" before iterating through it  - they save a small cache of a few records, but automatically delete it as you move.  THere is no way (in ODBC) to directly load row-by-row.  You'll need to use native API for your DB if you want to do that.  Forward only cursors (and FF-Only for SQL Server) are the "lightweight" way of accessing data in ODBC.